# All my .pdf files are being saved as .pdf.htlml in Android

Tags: android, google-chrome, firefox, android-download-manager

I have tried installing other browser but still no help.

I have finally reset the phone. And also tried after installing firefox. But issue still remains. I have reviewed the setting. Cleared data of these apps but still it is not helping.

Please help with the issue.

Comment: Othe browser? You did not tell which you used first.

Comment: @blackapps first I used chrome, then Hi browser(infinix mobile inbuilt browser), then firefox

Comment: Put the missing info in your post. Not as comment.

Answer (score 0):

Make your default browser Chrome then download any PDF opener in the Google Play Store (e.g. WPS Office, Google Docs, etc.).

Open Chrome Browser click the 3 dots in the top right, click Settings, click Downloads, and Turn On the "Ask to where to save Files".

Now download the pdf again and it will ask where to save and what is the name of the file. If you see the last extension filename is .html, delete it and make it just .pdf then you can open it using any PDF opener

Optional: Download Zarchiver on the Google Play Store. After you download PDF files, open Zarchiver and locate where you save the PDF then click it, Click the Arrow (right side) near Open and it will ask you to what apps should open this type of file.